# Folder Not Downloading In TFS 2008 - Problem With Mapping

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I have a project in TFS 2008 that has been successfully mapped to a local folder, however, one of the projects within my solution is marked as "Not Downloaded" within Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio, despite the local folder containing all of the appropriate files.

I've tried deleting my entire local folder and performing a "Get Specific Version" from Source Control Explorer, but it still states that this folder has not been downloaded when it quite clearly has been.

When I right-click on the folder in Source Control Explorer it gives me the option to map to a local folder, but when I select the correct folder it says that the folder is already mapped to another server folder.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Is there a way of finding out which server folder a local folder is mapped to?  Each time I perform a "Get Latest Version" or "Get Specific Version" the correct files are downloaded to my local folder, yet TFS still thinks the folder isn't mapped... help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a look at the same folder in the other branches of our team project, it turns out that one of our Dev branches was mapping that particular folder to the local folder that should have been used for the Release branch, hence the error message saying that the local folder was already mapped to another server folder.

This seems really strange as the rest of the Dev branch was mapped correctly, not to mention the fact that the Dev branch was branched from Main, not the Release branch, so it can't even have inherited the mapping from its parent.

Answer (score 5):

Two things to try:

1. The get version 1 trick:

   - In source control explorer, get specific version
   - Choose "Changeset"
   - For Changeset number, use "1"
   - Ensure both checkboxes are checked (overwrite writeable, and overwrite all)
   - Click "Get"
   - In Windows Explorer, delete any remaining local files that were there.
   - Attempt to "Get Latest" again.
2. The "nuke it from orbit" trick

   - Map a new workspace to a new folder.
   - Get latest
   - Delete the old workspace.
   - Shift your eyes back and forth and say "what mapping?" whenever someone asks you about the original workspace mapping.

Number 1 should work for you, but we've had to resort to number 2 in a couple of occasions.

Answer (score 1):

#1 did not work for me but something less drastic than #2 did. It seemed my folder wasn't even mapping even though it showed the folder in the local path.

This time when I mapped the folder, I unchecked the Recursive option and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with a directory (and subfolders) not downloading - I noticed it was greyed out in the Solution Explorer. Turns out all of the security entries had been cleared from that directory. After adding security entries allowing me to read (Advanced, Security, Add,...), I was able to use the "Get Specific Version" approach to get the directory.